# Communication between jquery and a content script

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, setinterval

I have the following content scripts loaded through my extension -

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["https://blah.blah/*"],      

          "js": ["src/script/lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" ,
                "src/script/Ext/Ext.ContentScript.js" ]
        }
    ]
```

In the content Script I have a function which uses the jquery's Ajax function to poll a server at regular intervals of time using the setInterval method.

Somehow as soon the method is called, the function inside the setInterval method has no access to any jquery operation. It seems like the culprit is chrome.storage.local api.
The callback does not have access to the other content scripts (Jquery in this case)

```
chrome.storage.local.get("savedData", function (userInfo) {

setInterval(function(){

//Fails to recognize the ajax method, throws "has not method ajax"

$.ajax({url:reqUrl, 
   success:function(data){

  }
});
});

}
```

Comment: It seems like if you make a call the chrome.storage api to retrieve saved data. The callback lose its access to Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

When i tried your scenario it worked for me

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://www.google.co.in/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "jquery.js",
                "script.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**script.js**

```
setInterval(function(){
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp",
  success:function (data){
    console.log("Success..");
  }});
},11000);
```

Why dont you use `recursive setTimeout()` instead of `SetInterval()`?

Comment: No timeout, will essentially give the default timeout - 4ms. Not sure if that is the reason.

Comment: @TusharMathur: I have tried with `no time out` i did not get any error!

Comment: it seems like an issue in my system only. But i have no clue as to how to resolve it. please let me know if you need some more information to help fix this. Thanks

Comment: @TusharMathur: Does this sample code in answer worked for you? If so, put your related code by editing your question, it can get us a broad picture.